# zsh completion according to a parameter

Tags: shell, zsh, zsh-completion

I am a quite a happy zsh user and especially appreciate its completion subsystem.
Recently I am trying to enhance some completion commands especially those I use often (ex. rm).
In zsh the following command:

```
rm <TAB>
```

makes zsh complete with the current directory's files as expected.
What I am trying to do is make zsh complete the following variant:

```
rm -r <TAB>
```

with only directories.

Any zsh Guru that knows how to parameter completion so that it takes in consideration the (-r)
parameter?

Comment: I'm not a guru, but I'll note that rmdir is already set up this way in zsh. :-)

Comment: @mjk: but AFIAK `rmdir` removes only empty directories which is not the same functionality `rm -r` provides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by editing the zsh completion function for `rm` to the desired behaviour.

The Z-shell completion functions are all defined somewhere on your system. On OSX, it's under `/usr/local/zsh/5.0.2/share/zsh/functions`. Linux probably has it somewhere similar.

The completion function for `rm` is defined in a file called `_rm`. It's rather small. (If you're interested, the completion for `rmdir` is defined in `_directories`).

To set the completion for `rm -r`, we need to modify the line that looks similar to this:

```
'(-r -R --recursive)'{-r,-R,--recursive}'[remove directories and their contents recursively]'
```

We add to the end of this line, inside the quote:

```
:*:file:_directories
```

*I'm pretty sure* that this informs `zsh` that the completion when the `-r` argument is given should consist of `files`, and the way we obtain those `files` is by using the `_directories` function (which only returns directories).

(I'm not *100%* sure, because `zsh` is a beast I'm still wrapping my little mind around).

Here's a sample usage:

[image]

---

Here's a diff of the changes, to make it extra clear :)

```
<   '(-r -R --recursive)'{-r,-R,--recursive}'[remove directories and their contents recursively]:*:file:_directories'
---
>   '(-r -R --recursive)'{-r,-R,--recursive}'[remove directories and their contents recursively]'
```

Comment: +1 & bounty for that great detailed answer. It worked perfectly fine on gentoo linux (the file was located under `/usr/share/zsh/5.0.2/functions/Completion/Unix/_rm`).